# Is this a famous pixel / Nintendo font?

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone know if this is a famous font?

I would really like to know the name of it.

[image]

Comment: lol, the ridiculous PETA game...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8-bit type in the age of 8-bit video games wasn't the same type of font files that you'd be using today on your average computer. They were instead bitmap files used within the game itself. I doubt Nintendo ever created actual font files for these and distributed them, but odds are that there are more than a few clones of this out there done by hobbyists (or even pros). Search for 'Nintendo' and 'bitmap' on the font sites out there.

Comment: It turned out that I found a font I like a lot more =) http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/FATAL_FURY.htm

Comment: This is a Mario spoof from not too long ago. So this was not made by Nintendo. (See how PETA whines about Mario being 'evil' http://features.peta.org/mario-kills-tanooki/ )

Answer (score 1):

### **Press Start 2P**

The closest font to this which can also be found in Google Fonts is Press Start 2P designed by CodeMan38: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Press+Start+2P

If not Press Start 2P, there are some more very similar looking fonts which this could be, I do not know if they are official or supported on all browsers:

- PixelNES designed by Neale Davidson
- Wayfarer's toy box
- Diary of an 8-bit mage